# Azure AD B2C - Google Tag Manager support

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a Azure AD B2C solution hopefully with Custom Policies and Branding.

A question is asked for me if Azure AD B2C supports Google tags and allow for tracking configuration for Google Analytics Events and setting up cross-domain tracking.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever JavaScript you like in your custom HTML files. Google tag manager works.

Comment: Thank Jas,

So the Java Scripts has to abide by the guidelines provided by Azure AD B2C

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#guidelines-for-using-javascript